# Should the intial state attributes should be null or undefined in react-redux reducer considering I want to make a post request to a database?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, react-redux

I am using Reactjs and react-redux along with spring boot and Postgres. While initializing the initial state attributes in reducer, should they be null or undefined considering I want to save them in the database?

eg:

```
const initialState = {
    rollNo: '',
    firstName: '',
    middleName: '',
}

const reducer = (initialState,action) => {
     ///
}
```

rollNo, firstName etc are fetched from the TextField from the form provided.
Should rollNo, firstName etc should be null or undefined?
I want to save them in the database and certain values can be null.
If I keep them null, I get the error:
 index.js:1375 Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
If I will keep them undefined, would they cause a problem in fetching them in backend specifically spring boot?

Thanks for your time. Any help would be wonderful :)

Answer (score 0):

Inputs in react cannot have the value of `null` which indicates -to React- they're uncontrolled components (They manage their state internally) then you go on giving them a value, to the input it doesn't make sense even if it did to your server.

What you should be doing is either nullifying the empty fields from the backend or nullifying them from the front end right before sending your request.